Can there be a proper class of Dedekind-finite cardinals?
To formalise the question: Does $\mathsf{ZF}$ prove the existence of an ordinal $\alpha$ such that, whenever $X$ is Dedekind-finite, there is an injection $X\to V_\alpha$? (Equivalently the existence of some set $Y$ such that every Dedekind-finite set embeds into $Y$).
A set $X$ is Dedekind-finite if there is no injection $\omega\to X$.
It is consistent that such an $\alpha$ exists. The obvious case is $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or any model of "Dedekind-finite if and only if finite", as in such models every Dedekind-finite set embeds into $V_\omega$.
Similarly, the answer is yes in any model of $\mathsf{SVC}$: If there is $A$ such that, for all $X$, there is an ordinal $\eta$ and a surjection $\eta\times A\to X$, then for all $X$ there is an $\eta$ such that $X$ embeds into $\mathscr{P}(A)\times\eta$. Taking $\eta$ minimally, if $X$ is Dedekind-finite then $\eta\leq\omega$, and thus every Dedekind-finite set embeds into $\mathscr{P}(A)\times\omega$.

The answer to the question in the body is no (and to that in the title, yes) - in Theorem 4.5 of this paper it is shown that there may be a proper class $K$ which is Dedekind-finite (which, for our purposes, we can take to mean all of its subsets are Dedekind-finite). Any proper class surjects onto the class of ordinals (by considering $V$-ranks), so for all large enough $\beta$, $K\cap V_\beta$ maps onto the Hartogs number of $|V_\alpha|$, and thus cannot embed into $V_\alpha$.
Theorem 4.6 shows that we can have way more - it is possible for the class $K$ to itself definably map onto $V$, which implies that any set is surjected onto by some Dedekind-finite set.

Not only there can be a proper class of them, every set can be the image of a Dedekind-finite set.
This is embedded in the proof of the Morris model, and in https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09285 it is made more explicit.

Has anyone checked if every set can be the image of a dually Dedekind-finite set?

@ElliotGlazer If $X$ is dually Dedekind-finite then already $\omega$ already cannot be the image of $X$ by definition.

@Ryan-Smith Dually Dedekind finite sets are those sets which cannot map onto their proper supersets.

@Glazer I think this is right.

@Ryan-Smith The sets that cannot map onto $\omega$ are called power Dedekind finite sets by Blass and me and are called weakly Dedekind finite sets by some others.

@Elliot: If you can do it once, you can do it forever. That's kind of the point in my paper.

@GuozhenShen: The @ notifications only work if you actually type in the user name, not the last name. That doesn't do anything.

@AsafKaragila I got it. Thanks!
